# Simple documentation in C#, where is service passed to index page code constructor?

Tags: c#

The documentation simple tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/upgrade-to-nullable-references and its whole code is in https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-migration/start

class in SimpleFeedReader/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs consumes parameter

```
public IndexModel(NewsService newsService)
        {
            _newsService = newsService;
}
```

also method of the newsservice is called in that file.

But there is never an expression which puts this service to this constructor. I do now understand how it goes there.

file https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-migration/start/SimpleFeedReader/Startup.cs
adds the service to hostbuilder. But also other services. I do not understand, why exactly this service goes to constructor of Index.cshtml.cs

Service is defined in https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-migration/start/SimpleFeedReader/Services

and host builder is :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace SimpleFeedReader
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

in
https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-migration/start/SimpleFeedReader/Program.cs

Where is newsservices fed into the constructor, and why from 3 services only it goes there?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

What you are witnessing here is something referred to as [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  The Startup.cs file is placing the NewsService into a dependency container which is then resolving the object when it is invoked from the IndexModel constructor.

So basically since the IndexModel relies on the NewsService, the dependency container creates a copy of it based on it's [service lifetime](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-service-lifetimes/) and then feeds it to the IndexModel any time the indexmodel gets called.

You can view more on how ASP.Net Core handles dependency injection by reviewing the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

The following is from a [FreeCodeCamp post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/)

> Let’s say we have a car class which contains various objects such as
> wheels, engine, etc.
>
> Here the car class is responsible for creating all the dependency
> objects. Now, what if we decide to ditch MRFWheels in the future and
> want to use Yokohama Wheels?
>
> We will need to recreate the car object with a new Yokohama
> dependency. But when using dependency injection (DI), we can change
> the Wheels at runtime (because dependencies can be injected at runtime
> rather than at compile time).
>
> You can think of DI as the middleman in our code who does all the work
> of creating the preferred wheels object and providing it to the Car
> class.
>
> It makes our Car class independent from creating the objects of
> Wheels, Battery, etc. There are basically three types of dependency
> injection:
>
> 1. constructor injection: the dependencies are provided through a class constructor.
> 2. setter injection: the client exposes a setter method that the injector uses to inject the dependency.
> 3. interface injection: the dependency provides an injector method that will inject the dependency into any client passed to it. Clients
>    must implement an interface that exposes a setter method that accepts
>    the dependency.
>
> So now its the dependency injection’s responsibility to:
>
> - Create the objects
> - Know which classes require those objects
> - And provide them all those objects
>
> If there is any change in objects, then DI looks into it and it should
> not concern the class using those objects. This way if the objects
> change in the future, then its DI’s responsibility to provide the
> appropriate objects to the class.